# Google Console not accepting my 64 bit Android App Bundle File from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-console-developer

I am trying to uplaod my game i have created `64bit .abb` (android app bundle) file with unity. i have fulfilled all requirements that unity provided and converted to 64 bit. i have also analysed .abb file and found all .so files needed for both 32 bit and 64 bit but when i upload it on console it says that

> .ABB FILE NOT COMPATIBLE TO GOOGLE 64-BIT REQUIREMENT

Please help what i am missing or what should i do? I have attached picture of .so files in 64-bit folder in .abb file:

[image]

Comment: I still have the same problem. I changed Scripting Backend and select 64 bit and made .aab as explained in Android Docs here https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#unity-developers but it did not resolve my problem. Any luck?